# BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback not finding BLE devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working with Bluetooth low energy devices and I have two BLE devices. While testing I found in pixel or **stock android devices** one of the BLE device not discovered by BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback.
But stock android device's bluetooth application found same BLE device. Don't know what is wrong with the BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback.

I am very new in BLE device connection any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: what is special to that device? Are you sure that it is LE? Are you sure you don't use any filters when scanning? Are you sure that you are scanning long enough? Also AFAIK default bluetooth scanning uses Classic scan (which finds both Classic and LE devices)

Comment: both devices are identical just switch off time is increased to 15 secs . And I am not using any filter while scanning. I am scanning for 5 minutes. And other devices are able to find the same no issue with them.

Comment: Samsung J7 and HTC desire are able to detect same BLE device

Comment: Maybe you could show the code you're using? Have you tried another BLE scan app on play store?

Comment: @Emil yes I tried LightBlue and BLE Scanner both. But problem is same.

Comment: Is there any possibility BLE device is not developed properly or it is at android side problem

Comment: It would be helpful to see your scanning code. Also, with new versions of Android make sure your app has location permissions and your GPS is on. The location permissions is important. Anytime you do a fresh install of your app you need to enable the permission again in the App Info settings. Or request permission through user interaction.

Comment: It's a HW issue then

Comment: @ck221 i have applied both permissions Location enabling and  storage.